# fill checkbox when text is in text area in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a text area form like this one:

```
<input id="sg_0" name="sjalfgefid" type="text" class="letur hvitur" size="8" maxlength="40" value=""></td>
```

and a Checkbox next to it:

```
<input type="Checkbox" id="cb0" name="innsent" tegund="val" gildi="eink" value="0" number="0" parents="1" onclick="hakaVid(this)">
```

I want the checkbox to be filled when some text is written in the text area. And when the user deletes all the text from the textbox, I want the checkbox to update immediately
How can I possibly do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach an `onKeyUp` event handler to the `<input>` and modify the checkbox's value according to `this.value.length`.

```
<input id="sg_0" name="sjalfgefid" type="text" class="letur hvitur" 
       size="8" maxlength="40" value="" 
       onkeyup="document.getElementById('cb0').checked = this.value.length > 0;">
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qG5Cu/

**UPDATE** You might be interested on using the `onInput` event handler instead of `onkeyup`. See this link for more information: [Using the oninput event handler with onkeyup/onkeydown as its fallback](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/oninput)

Comment: what if I wanted the 0 to differ from an id of the textbox ?
Lets say that the next text area is 'cb1'.
This does not work. If k is an ID:
document.getElementById('cb'+ k ).checked = this.value.length > 0

Comment: `k` has to be a defined variable. How are you generating these components? Just put the proper variable name in the loop you're using to generate them, or set the event handler programmatically (`input.onkeyup = function(){ ... }`).

Comment: Or you can extract the relevant part of the ID (the number) from `this.id` using `substring`: `document.getElementById('cb' 
 + this.id.substring(3)).checked = this.value.length > 0;"`.You'll really have to elaborate on what you want to achieve and how are you generating these components

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I used the this.id.substring to get the ID from the text area because the number is always the same as the checkbox. :)

Comment: One more question. What if I want the checkbox not to be able to check/uncheck when some characters are on the texta area. Only when the text area is empty. How would I do that ?

Comment: Just set the checkbox's `disabled` property accordingly. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qG5Cu/1/. Take into account that `disabled` `<input>`'s don't make it to the request when submitting a `<form>`.

Comment: What can I do so the request will be submitted ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try with input events, check w3c:
[input tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Comment: **W3c != w3schools**. http://w3fools.com, Use MDN for referencing to JS/CSS/html/... documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org

Comment: [W3Schools](http://w3fools.com/) is not affiliated with the W3C in any way, and is an often an inaccurate resource. [This](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) is the W3C spec on `<input>` elements.